# How do I modify the "group" label?

Tags: organic-groups

I would like to use Organic Groups in a way that would make each group a company. Is there an expeditious way to do a mass modification of the label "group" wherever it appears on the UI? I'd like the references to "group" to be changed to "company".

Answer (score 2):

I think the [String overrides](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module would be the quickest way. The module:

> Provides a quick and easy way to replace any text on the site.